# JQuery "#id.class" Selector Mashup

Tags: javascript, web, jquery-selectors, jquery

I have some bullet points which I want to show more text below them on clicking them. They are both two separate Ps that are paired together by sharing a common id. So, what I am trying to do below is to find the element with (id_same_as_this.class), so that the element with the class "expand" as well as the id that matches the clicked on P is toggled. Does that make sense?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expandable").click(function(){
        $(this.attr('id')+"."+"expand").toggle(800);
    });     
});
```

I only ask if the above code could be made to work because it would make the expandable bullet points in my web page significantly less code intensive than a lot of the examples I have read about.

Comment: There shouldn't be "a common id". ID's are unique to an element and shouldn't be the same as another element's

Comment: Something *like* that can be made to work, yes, but you cannot use the same `id` on more than one element, that's invalid (and speaking pragmatically, it just doesn't work). Or did you intend to have a space before the `.`? That would make it valid, selecting an element with class `expand` underneath the element. But you wouldn't want to do it like you're doing it above (you wouldn't need an ID at all).

Comment: Think hierarchically. You dont need to duplicate the id, you just select the classed item subordinate to that id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  $(this.attr('id')+"."+"expand").toggle(800);
```

Must be

```
  $("#" + this.id +".expand").toggle(800);
```

You missed the `#` there. That said, you shouldn't ever have a common ID. [By definition IDs are meant to be unique](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute). If you have the same ID on multiple elements, while it may work now on the browsers you try, you have no guarantee it won't break in the next rev of jQuery (or Chrome, or Konqueror, or iOS Safari). There's also no *reason* to do it. You could just use classes or `data-*` attributes.

Comment: Thanks both of you. That was very quick. Also, Ids are only unique if the element has no other differentiating class, or tag, or something like that. With those changes my code works.

@hungerpain - If you take the unique id comment off the end (or alter it) i will accept it as your answer.

Comment: @RudiKershaw -- No, an ID is an ID, and an ID MUST be unique.

Comment: *"Also, Ids are only unique if the element has no other differentiating class, or tag, or something like that."* No, `id` values **must be unique**, full stop. It doesn't matter what class or  whatever they have on them: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute: *"The value **must be unique** amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree"* (e.g., document).

Comment: @RudiKershaw: It is true, and the code may work on some browsers, but not others. That's the way things are when you break the rules, sometimes you get lucky, but it **will** come back and bite you.

Comment: @RudiKershaw Pls read this : http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blfaqmultiIDs.htm
Its not necessary, but its important. For your markup to be valid HTML, (which webkit browsers sometimes expect from you) each ID must be used only once per page.

Comment: It works on IE, Chrome, Firefox and Safari. It still works even on IE 8 and the other browsers aren't having any problems no matter how far back I roll them.

Comment: @Rudi. IDs are required to be unique. It might work in your browser right now. But try another browser or another version. You're only asking for trouble.

Comment: @ Rudi, so if you select $('#yourid'), which one is it you want?

Comment: Doesn't matter. I take the unique value, and add a .class to the end and there is only 1 #id.class that matches.

Comment: @RudiKershaw : Think of it this way. Imagine you're in a school. You've got a unique identification. Thats unique to u. Only to u. Thats how an ID is. You belong to a grade. There might be a lot of ppl in a grade. Thats a class. Its not wrong to have multiple IDs in a page, but its semantically incorrect. Try selecting an ID which is assigned to multiple elements. You'll get only the first one. Thats the problem right there.

Comment: Yea, but I am not "getting" the person, I am getting the id of the person and then identifying the one I want with a separate identifier. Using your example, if there were two kids with the "id" Bob, then asking for bob won't tell me which one I need... if however, I just use the id and append a last name and use the new Bob.Smith, I can't confuse it with the other kid.

Comment: @RudiKershaw: But that's not an ID anymore. You're relying on jQuery to return *all* of the elements that match your ID selector and then filter them with your class selector. `$('#bob.smith')` works because it's passed into `querySelectorAll`, but `$('#bob').filter('.smith')` won't.

Comment: I understand that... That's why it works. I am not saying it's good practice (it's terrible practice), all that I am saying, is that it can be used that way, and it does work. And whilst that is the case, I can't accept an answer that is proclaiming something that is not true.

Comment: @RudiKershaw: All due respect, but this is just dumb. The issue isn't whether it happens to work in the limited subset of browsers you've tried. The issue is that is **absolutely zero reason** to blatantly violate the specification and competely misuse `id` values. None. Zero. If you want to assign the same thing to more than one element, make it a class or a `data-*` attribute. End of. [`id` values **must** be unique on the page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute).

Comment: With all due respect your comment is dumb. You misunderstand me entirely. My issue is not that I want to use it and I am going to because it works. My issue was that I wasn't going to select an answer as correct based on false information. The truth is always an issue. Even if it's a great answer, if it's technically wrong, I won't select it. This answer has been edited and is now correct, and so I selected it. It was edited and selected as correct before you even commented, so I don't really see what YOUR issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this will work but you need a # before the ID

Answer (score 1):

> They are both two separate Ps that are paired together by sharing a common id.

IDs are unique. Two elements can't share a common ID, as that defeats the whole purpose of having a unique identifier. JavaScript assumes that you're using valid HTML, so `document.getElementById()` will return only the first element with a matching `id`. By using non-unique IDs, things will start breaking [in unpredictable ways](http://jsfiddle.net/WN7yK/):

```
$('#foo').find('.bar') // Won't search past first #foo
$('#foo .bar')         // Will search past first #foo in IE8+
```

Try restructuring your HTML to make this task easier. Maybe you could do something like this:

```
<ul id="bullets">
    <li>
        <h2>Title</div>
        <div>Text</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And then use a simple event handler:

```
$('#bullets h2').click(function() {
    $(this).next().toggle(800);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `id` values for this at all (which is good, as from the comments on hungerpain's answer, you're using the same `id` value on more than one element, [which is invalid](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)).

Just do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expandable").click(function(){
        $(this).find(".expand").toggle(800);
    });     
});
```

That will find the element with the class `expand` within the `expandable` that was clicked. No relying on unspecified behavior of selectors.

If you really need that data on the `expandable`, just put it in a `data-*` attribute. So instead of this invalid structure:

```
<!-- INVALID -->
<div id="foo27" class="expandable">
    <div class="expand">...</div>
</div>
<div id="foo27" class="expandable">
    <div class="expand">...</div>
</div>
```

Do this

```
<!-- VALID -->
<div data-id="foo27" class="expandable">
    <div class="expand">...</div>
</div>
<div data-id="foo27" class="expandable">
    <div class="expand">...</div>
</div>
```

Use the above code to do the expansion. If you need the value, use `.attr("data-id")` or `.data("id")` to get it.